# Getting rows between date range in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I am having a serious issue I can not figure out. I am trying to return rows from MySQL database that have a Start date between two given dates and an End date as well. Here is my php code to query the database:

```
$getRooms = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM Tarifas 
    WHERE Start BETWEEN '2013-01-10' AND '2013-01-13' 
    AND   End   BETWEEN '2013-01-10' AND '2013-01-13'
");
```

Start and End are set up as DATE fields

my database is set up as follows:

```
ID | RoomId | Start      | End
--------------------------------------
4  | 34562  | 2013-01-09 | 2013-10-23
```

If anyone can help me figure out why this is not working, it would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Do you get a PHP or a MySQL error?

Comment: Unless the data you have provided is incorrect, you have an end date in the table as `2013-10-23` but you are looking for `end` dates `BETWEEN '2013-01-10' AND '2013-01-13'` -- that data doesn't match so you will get no results.

Comment: Do you have records that meet this criteria?

Comment: What is the type of the `Start` and `End` columns? (Can you give the statement that created the `Tarifas` table?)

Comment: Are you checking for date conflicts (e.g. when the whole date range or part of it lies inside a date range stored in database)?

Comment: it will exactly have no result because `2013-10-23` is not between `2013-01-10' AND '2013-01-13'`

Comment: I would also add, that criteria for the `Start` column is also wrong: 2013-01-09 is out of 2013-01-10 - 2013-01-13 range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your query and sample data, perhaps you are looking for a [SQL Query to Find Overlapping or Conflicting Date Ranges](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2012/06/sql-query-overlapping-date-ranges.html). The query would be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Tarifas 
WHERE '2013-01-13' >= `Start` AND `End` >= '2013-01-10'
```

`2013-01-13` is greater than `2013-01-09` -- and -- `2013-10-23` is greater than `2013-01-10` so Tarifas #4 will be returned since it conflicts/overlaps with the specified dates.

Comment: He only stated that " I am trying to return rows from MySql database the have a Start date between two given dates and an End date as well."

Comment: I just inferred this from the sample data and query (and the little knowledge that I have about booking "rooms" and rateplans). The input range is `2013-01-13` thru `2013-01-13` and he PROBABLY wants row id #4 to be returned.

Comment: This worked well, I just had to modify it a bit to WHERE start_date<= 'mydate' AND end_date >= 'mydate'
Thank you very much